# Enabling HDR on Windows 11 & full backlight makes the desktop dark, not dull

Tags: windows, windows-11, desktop, hdr, 120hz

I have Windows 11 HTPC, GTX 1080 connected to LG TV at 4k 120Hz. Everything works well except even with full backlight my TV goes dark with HDR enabled. I mean dark with bright colors, not dull. My TV is still set to 100% backlight but it looks more like 10-20%. Playing HDR videos on MPC-HC is dark but definitely HDR. Switching to a game with lesser resolution like PixelJunk Monsters gives me the full backlight and the little HDR logo is shown briefly in the top right corner.